# flutter : how toggle nightmode in flutter_pdfview

Tags: flutter, pdf, dart

im using flutter_pdfview package for showing the pdf in my app.
im create the button and in onPress() im setState() the nightmode to true but nightmode not apply to the pdf.
what should I do ??

Answer (score 2):

Use ColorFiltered widget to get night mode. Here's mine snippet

```
ColorFiltered(
          colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.white, BlendMode.difference),
          //colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.black54, BlendMode.darken),
          child: //Your pdf widget or any widget,
        ),
```

I have commented out other properties for you. Try and examine them. BlendMode.difference creates inverted color. BlendMode.darken creates a overlap color like blue filter.

Doc reference: [ColorFilteredClass](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ColorFiltered-class.html)